# Why am I unable to pass a Radiobutton variable from one class to different class using Tkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, radio-button

Let me start this off by saying that I have scoured stack overflow and I have been unable to find an answer to my issue. I have found something that is very close, but I still am unable to resolve my issue. If you are aware of a link that would be helpful, please include it in the comments.

I am relatively new to programming in Python so please provide constructive criticism if you see any incorrect programming practices or if anything can be programmed in a more pythonic style.

I'm having a problem with getting a variable from a radio button in one class and printing it out in a label on a different frame in a different class. FYI: As of right now, all classes are in the same file but I plan to change that after I complete the program.

Here is my controller class:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.emotion_list = ["angry", "sad", "happy", "fearful", "surprised", "curious",
                             "anxious", "chill"] 

        self.title("Application")

        self.frames = {}

        inner_container = ttk.Frame(self)
        inner_container.grid(sticky='ew')

        for FrameClass in (ChooseFeelings, ChooseState):
            frame = FrameClass(inner_container, self, self.pages)
            self.frames[FrameClass] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(ChooseFeelings)

    def show_frame(self, inner_container):
        frame = self.frames[inner_container]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_frame(self, classname):
        """Returns an instance of a frame given its class name as a string"""
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None
```

As you can see, I have included a method at the bottom of my controller class that can be called to create an instance of any class when needed.

I have also not included all classes in the self.frames dictionary because they don't pertain to the issue at hand.

Here I have the class that displays the radio buttons to the user. I am well aware that as it looks right now, they aren't organized on the frame. There are other widgets on the frame that I am omitting from the class because they don't pertain to the issue.

```
class ChooseFeelings(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)

        emotion_container = ttk.Frame(self, padding='100 15 30 15')
        emotion_container.grid(sticky='ew')

        self.controller = controller
        self.selected_emotion = tk.StringVar()

        move_on_button = ttk.Button(emotion_container, text="Click me when you are ready to move on",
                                    command=lambda: [controller.show_frame(ChooseState), print(selected_emotion.get())])

        move_on_button.pack(side='top')

        for emotions in self.controller.emotion_list:
            ttk.Radiobutton(emotion_container, text=emotions, variable=self.selected_emotion,
                            value=emotions).pack(side='bottom')
```

After clicking the move_on_button, I print out to the console the variable that I hope to get in the label on the next frame.

Here is the frame where the variable should print out to the user.

```
class ChooseState(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)

        self.controller = controller

        state_container = ttk.Frame(self, padding='100 15 30 15')
        state_container.grid(sticky='ew')

        self.emotion_label = ttk.Label(state_container, text=f"You chose {self.get_feels()} as your emotion.")

        self.emotion_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

    def get_feels(self):
        feelings_frame = self.controller.get_frame("ChooseFeelings")
        user_emotion = feelings_frame.selected_emotion.get()
        return user_emotion


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, the get_feels method is used to create an instance of the ChooseFeelings class, then the variable 'user_emotion' is supposed to hold the selected radio button variable. Once that happens, the 'user_emotion' variable is returned and should be printed out to the screen. Or so I thought....

In the ChooseState class, I should be printing out in 'self.emotion_label', the chosen radio button variable from the previous class. Instead all I get is "You chose as your emotion". All I would like to do is pass the radio button variable from the previous class to this class without any errors.

If anyone has any insight on how to fix this problem it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!